# Check max cpu clock speed in linux

Tags: 20.04, kernel, cpu-load, cpufreq

I have seen this question multiple times but no answer to the point.

I am on Ubuntu 20.04, CPU is R9 5950x.

All I want is a stress test where it shows the max clock speed (in MHz) and
what a single core or all cores went up to.

Is it available in Linux?

I don't think `sysbench` or `stress-ng` provides that.

I am not asking this for peace of mind. I am an academic coder and I am not satisfied with the single core or multi core performance.

With `lscpu` I never found the clock speed going above `4.7 GHz` on single core load and all core speed never goes above `3.8 GHz`.

I have to determine if my CPU or the cooling is faulty.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is something the BIOS will tell your so anything related to that should be available from the `dmidecode` tool. Example, filtering on "Max" tells me mine are capped at 2000MHz:

```
$ sudo dmidecode | grep Max
        Max Speed: 2000 MHz
        Max Speed: 2000 MHz
        Maximum Capacity: 13 GB
```

---

1 module shows me ...

```
Handle 0x1001, DMI type 4, 32 bytes
Processor Information
        Socket Designation: CPU 1
        Type: Central Processor
        Family: Other
        Manufacturer: Google
        ID: F0 06 03 00 FF FB 8B 1F
        Version: Not Specified
        Voltage: Unknown
        External Clock: Unknown
        Max Speed: 2000 MHz
        Current Speed: 2000 MHz
        Status: Populated, Enabled
        Upgrade: Other
        L1 Cache Handle: Not Provided
        L2 Cache Handle: Not Provided
        L3 Cache Handle: Not Provid
```

Comment: These are just specifications which cannot be trusted on a new hardware. For example`lscpu` on `5.11` kernel shows max frequency 7.2 GHz! Is there a stress test that  shows max (and avg) clock speed during that test?

Comment: Bit that is ALL you have. The OS depends on the hardware to provide this :)  Is there a stress test that shows max (and avg) clock speed during that test?  No don't think so )

Comment: Thanks. Got a clear answer. I will look no further.